# Overloaded controller methods in Swagger

Tags: java, spring, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have a Spring REST application. I am using Swagger for API documentation purpose.

What I have any my REST controllers are, methods with `@RequestMapping`.
I have two overloaded methods, they differ in terms of arguments.
But Swagger UI only shows one.

Is it my approach which is wrong (overloading controller methods) or it is a bug in Swagger?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is a limitation in swagger specification. However if you are using springfox, you can configure your `Docket` with  `docket.enableUrlTemplating(true)`. This will allow your overloaded methods to show up in the service document.

Comment: Hey @dilip-krishnan, do you mind take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59096880/swagger-ui-support-for-overloaded-methods-springfox-swagger-ui-2-9-0-rfc6570 ?